# Why Gauss' law is applied?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, gauss-law, coulombs-law

Why [Gauss' law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law) is applied? Why is there a need of finding electric field by Gauss' law if we can find the electric field through Coulomb's law?

or has it got more applications than Coulomb's law?

Comment: Try to calculate the electric field of a sphere: using Coulomb's law and the using Gauss' law. Then you tell me which you prefer.

Comment: Gauss law is a $better$ mathematical tool in the $appropriate$ cases of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah. Coulomb's law only serves with static charges. Gauss law is valid with any charge distribution (it doesn't matter whether they are moving in any possible way). It's actually one of the 4 Maxwell equations.

Apart from that, even in the realm of electrostatics, Gauss' law is also very well suited to deal with situations of high symmetry in which the application of Coulomb's law would be really tedious. For example the typical example, a spherical charge distribution, or a cylindrical one. Imagine what  would be like to calculate the electric field for those systems using Coulomb's law.